# How can I disable the "Recent Actions" widget from Django Admin interface?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I dont want to show the **recent action widget** in django admin site.I don't know how to get this done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can override the `admin/index.html` template to disable the display. There's 
a sidebar block you might want to change/remove.

Conditionally enabling or disabling actions
ModelAdmin.get_actions(request)
Finally, you can conditionally enable or disable actions on a per-request (and hence per-user basis) by overriding ModelAdmin.get_actions().

This returns a dictionary of actions allowed. The keys are action names, and the values are (function, name, short_description) tuples.

Most of the time you'll use this method to conditionally remove actions from the list gathered by the superclass. For example, if I only wanted users whose names begin with 'J' to be able to delete objects in bulk, I could do the following:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if request.user.username[0].upper() != 'J':
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions
```

i edited the answer you may find more like this at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: *The first line answers the question. Second line onwards describes a solution to another problem (that's not asked in this question)

Comment: How do you override the admin/index.html template to disable the display?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the answer given by @Devjosh. To override existing template, all you have to do is create `templates/admin` folder and add `index.html` in it with these lines to get rid of  **Recent Actions** sidebar:-

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}

{% block sidebar  %}
{% endblock %}
```