# How to stop logging Recent actions and History in Django 2.* admin panel?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

to all!

I'm using Django 2.* and have no idea how to remove this useless for me logging features from Django Admin panel.

**I need completely stop tracking all recent actions and logging history in Django admin panel.**

Please help me find out a solution.
(i've Googled well enough before asking for help here)

[image: History in Django admin]
[image: Recent actions in Django admin]

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template) is the part in the docs that tells how you can do it; I didn't want to write all of it here thinking that the link actually would be more helpful. Hope it helps.

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674250/how-can-i-disable-the-recent-actions-widget-from-django-admin-interface

Comment: [This article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template) do the trick but not exactly i wanted, it ca hide History button and Recent actions, but it doesn't stops logging process

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These logging entries are created in 3 methods of ModelAdmin: log_addition, log_change and log_deletion. So what you need to do is override them in all of your admin classes inheriting form ModelAdmin and simply return in the body of these methods.

If you have more than a few admin classes, you can make a mixin class that overrides these methods and inherit from it in all your admin classes. Note that you need to inherit from the mixin before **admin.ModelAdmin**.

For example:

```
class DontLog:
    def log_addition(self, *args):
        return

    # Do same for log_change and log_deletion

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(DontLog, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

To remove history buttons, you'll want to edit the template as described in the admin docs linked to in one of the comments to your question:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template